# How to compare WKNavigation object

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I need to know wether navigation at start(did commit navigation) and end(ie. did finish navigation) are same or not during WkWebview's loading process.

I tried to compare WKNavigation object which the documentation states

> ...uniquely identify a webpage load from start to finish

[WKNavigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigation)

I either used "==" or "===" to compare two objects but never able to get match.

Is it even possible to compare WKNavigation object and if so how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.2, you can use the `.isEqual()` method to compare two objects that conform to `Equatable`, as `WKNavigation` does.

Use-case as below:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // initial vc setup, including WKWebView instance
    // initialRequest is set as an instance variable for your view controller

    initialRequest = webView.load(someUrlRequest)
}

...

public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    guard let navigation.isEqual(initialRequest) else { return }

    // do your finished loading logic here
}
```